# GeoServer: extract raster data of a time period

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

is there a way to use WMS->GetFeatureInfo specifying a TIME period (eg: 2014-01-01/2014-03-01) to extract a series of values from a raster layer loaded from a GeoServer instance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment, no. It may be added in the future though, it's not the first time I hear this request. I don't have a ETA, it depends on when funding to work on it shows up.
In the meantime, a somewhat complex workaround might be to configure the image mosaic index as a WFS feature type, query it by date, figure out the exact time values intersected by the interval, and then do N GetFeatureInfo requests, one for each of those values.

Comment: any risk to overload GeoServer with so much requests? can we work on customize response templates instead?